# How to check if segue is in progress

Tags: ios, uikit, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I sometimes manually invoke segue using

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueID", sender: self)
```

The problem is sometimes the function containing above line is invoked twice in succession. This causes segue animation to be aborted in the middle and restart, which looks weird. How do I check if segue animation is already in progress?

Comment: performSegue later calls the prepareForSegue method .

Comment: So how do I test if segue is midway or done?

Answer (score 1):

The method [`shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue) is called automatically to check if the `segue` you try to execute should really be performed:

```
func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool
```

> Determines whether the segue with the specified identifier should be performed.

The `Bool` return value determines if the segue will be performed:

> true if the segue should be performed or false if it should be ignored.

Try to incorporate one of the following checks inside `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` and return `true` or `false` depending on the outcome:

1. Check if the segue's destination view controller is already loaded into memory with [`isViewLoaded`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2097563-isviewloaded)?

   ```
   override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

       // check if the destination view controller is not yet loaded into memory
       if !target.isViewLoaded {
           return true // perform the segue
       }    
       return false // do not perform the segue
   }
   ```
2. Check if the segue's destination view controller is already presented with [`isBeingPresented`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2097564-isbeingpresented)?

   ```
   override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

       // check if the destination view controller is not presented yet
       if !target.isBeingPresented {
           return true // perform the segue
       }    
       return false // do not perform the segue
   }
   ```

You need to get the target ViewController depending on how your app is set up. You can identify it with a identifier or by checking the array of presented or child view controllers on your current view controller for an already existing view controller of the target class type. I would require more information to give a more specific solution.

Comment: What is sender here?

Comment: „The object that initiated the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue.“ Use the code above in [`shouldperformseguewithidentifier:sender:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformseguewithidentifier). I will update my post when I get back home.